# How to read a file using tensorflow which is uploaded by django

Tags: django, python-3.x, tensorflow, django-rest-framework

I have uploaded a file using django & django rest framework,an that image we have **InMemoryUploadedFile**. Now I want to read this file using tensorlfow.

serializers.py

```
class ImageClassificationSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    image = serializers.ImageField()
```

views.py

```
class ImageClassificationView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)
    serializer_class = ImageClassificationSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            input_name = "file_reader"
            file_reader = tensorflow.read_file(serializer.validated_data['image'], input_name)

            print file_reader
        response = {
            "success": True
        }
        return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

when I am reading file, I am geeting below mentioned error :

```
Expected string passed to parameter 'filename' of op 'ReadFile', got <InMemoryUploadedFile: mobile_image.jpeg (image/jpeg)> of type 'InMemoryUploadedFile' instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Tensorflow expects a filename of a local file, instead of the file object being passed now. You could write the upload to a temporary file and then pass the path of that file to Tensorflow, something along these lines:

```
import tempfile
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as tempfile:
    tempfile.write(serializer.validated_data['image'].read())
    tempfile.flush()
    file_reader = tensorflow.read_file(tempfile.name)
```

This is not a very effiecient method, be careful if you're uploading large files.